# Rename iPhone Project

Tags: iphone

I've developed an iPhone app but found out that I can't userhe ne I've been working with for my project.  Is it possible to rename my app in XCode or so I have to go through a bunch of te source files and do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename just the .xcodeproj file to change the name in the finder. To change the name that appears on the phone, you need to go to the Target Info (right-click on the target in the file tree on the left) and change the Product Name. If you've modified your info.plist, you may need to change it there as well.

Comment: And for others who might be thinking of renaming their app to have two versions of it for testing, you'll need to change the identifier as well (Info.plist).

Comment: Nimrod's answer was more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

See "Rename" under the Project menu in Xcode.

Comment: For XCode4, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4/5416693#5416693

Answer (score 1):

> Project >> Rename...

only available in XCode 3.2 or newer (so you need Snow Leopard to use this feature)

You still have to rename the folder your project is in manually though!

Comment: Rename a folder??? Oh noes!

Obviously there's no excuse for not having upgraded to Snow Leopard by now....

Comment: XCode 3.2 renames everything but not the folder the project is in. I think this is appropriate behavior in this case! Not a big deal.