# How to rename project name in Xcode 4.x

Tags: xcode, xcode4, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming projects in XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4)

In 3.2, you go to project, then rename. I can't find it anywhere in Xcode 4 even though the official documents tells you to do just that for 3.2 or later.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select the project in the Project Navigator (Cmd-1) and open the File Inspector in the right sidebar (Cmd-Opt-1). There, change the Project Name.

Comment: This doesn't work for me... I keep getting a 'fatal error' message