# What is the equivalent of Project->Rename in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, project, rename, ios4

Xcode 3 had the easy to use  Project-> Rename in case I wanted to change the name of my app being developed. I don't see the option in Xcode 4 anymore. Whats the best way to rename your app without any crashes?

Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming projects in XCode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⌘+1, click the blue node with the project name, wait a second, click again (the name becomes editable). That's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered here as well

[Renaming projects in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4)