# New PhoneGap / Cordova iOS project won't run after renaming

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, rename

When you create a fresh Cordova project it's called HelloCordova, which is also the app icon name. If I rename the project in XCode it will no longer run in the iPad simulator.

*I am running Cordova 3 and Xcode 4.6.3 on OS X 10.8.4*

### Steps to reproduce

In terminal:

- `cordova create Survey com.domain.mysurveyap`
- `cd Survey`
- `cordova platform add ios`
- `cordova build`

This creates the XCode project in platforms/ios/. I then open it in XCode. The project is called `HelloCordova`. I hit run with the target set to iPad 6.0 Simulator.

`Running HelloCordova on iPad 6.0 Simulator. No issues`

Good. I get the Hello World app up.

---

Next I rename the project by changing the `Project Name` in the Identity panel. I'm doing this

- a) because I don't want my project to be called 'HelloCordova'.
- b) because the name here seems to dictate what the App Icon is labelled as on the device.

I rename it to 'Survey':

[image]

Xcode prompts me to rename related project content items for me. I click 'Rename'

[image]

After renaming, I go to run in the simulator again. Now it won't run. I see a 'Build succeeded' overlay for a moment. But in the status panel at the top it says:

`Finished running Survey.app on iPad 6.0 Simulator. No issues.`

[image]

I notice that it still shows 'HelloCordova' in the scheme selector. I have tried running 'Clean' and also restarting XCode.

This is a completely fresh PhoneGap project with no modifications. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385542/project-crashes-after-rename?rq=1)

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg Thanks, sadly no luck. Weirdly, within `platforms/ios` my project is called `Survey.xcodeproj` but the adjacent folder is still called `HelloCordova`.

Comment: That is weird. I'm not sure either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the renaming was failing, and I can't explain that `"Finished running... No issues"` problem. But: `cordova create` takes an extra argument that was missing.

This solves the problem:

`cordova create Survey com.domain.mysurveyap "Survey"`

The final `"Survey"` there sets the project name on creation, thus avoiding the need to rename the project in the first place.