# How to change the DisplayName of an iOS Application?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I know there are so many answers related to my question, such like.

[Programmatically rename an XCode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171457/programmatically-rename-an-xcode-project)
[Renaming xcode 4 project and the actual folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262613/renaming-xcode-4-project-and-the-actual-folder)

etc.

But look at following my code:

```
NSString *plistPath = @"...../TestingAPI-Info.plist";
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
[dictionary setObject:@"myTestingApp" forKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
[dictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

I am changing the name of apps icon by above code,

[image]

Changed name **"MySuperApp => myTestingApp"**

SO, Is it valid to change by using above code ? I have fear of app rejection ?? I also want to set all changes through above code like, **Bundle identifier, Bundle name..etc** ?

Is it valid or not ?? By using above code apple reject my application or not ??

Comment: The requirement is very unusual, you wake in the morning and the app name has changed, you won't find the app, whats the use ?

Comment: But this will change the project name or application display name?

Answer (score 4):

As rckoenes said correctly, this won't work on the device. Any bundle contents are readonly, including the info.plist. You can not overwrite it.

To clarify:
Just open up the Info.plist file in Xcode and rename it to whatever you want. You don't need any code for this. You will find the `YourProjectName-Info.plist` file within your Xcode project.

Comment: Thanks for replay - But if I want to change app name for only once and also after name is changed in simulator then I want to  upload to AppStore so anything is wrong ? apple reject it or not ?? i also want to change  Bundle identifier, Bundle name..etc ?

Comment: @TheKing the app store rules don't matter. It's impossible to change the name of an app. You can do it during development but you can't do it when it has been deployed by the store. You would have to jail break the phone to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just open up the Info.plist file in Xcode and rename it to whatever you want. You don't need any code for this. You will find the `YourProjectName-Info.plist` file within your Xcode project.

Answer (score 2):

The `writeToFile` call will not work i.e. the contents will never get update in the `Info.plist` file. API call may return a false success but contents of that file will never change since application bundle is *read-only* (obviously the contents within it as well).

As per [Appstore review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) there is one which suggests,

> 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected.

But whether app bundle falls under *"designated container area"* is a matter of speculation because only Apple can clarify this. AFAIK I have not read anywhere about app getting reject for attempting to write into application bundle.

**As a side note**: It may not be a good idea to change application name randomly without the users consent.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is very unusual, app name is your brand it is finalized with lot of suggestions and thinking. What is benefits of this and why is your requirements to change name likewise.