# Change application name in Xcode / Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4, rename

What's the most efficient way to change my **Mac OS X** application name in Xcode?

*(I know it's easy; I've done it in the past but I can't really remember how... :/)*

**What I mean :**

- Let's say, I've got a **Project/Application** named `oldName`.
- How do I change that to `newName`, so that this new name appears everywhere it should be? (Application name, bundle identifier, About dialog, Dock, etc)

Comment: maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4

Comment: @IkmalEzzani Thanks! This is the correct answer - post it as a proper answer and you'll get all the credit you deserve! ;-)

Comment: thank u @Dr.Kameleon, the fact that I starved for rep is not denied. by it will confuse other users as to point to another SO question. it will help them better to edit your original post and redirect others to the answers link. you can +1 on comment and I'll receive them too. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click your project on the left at the top where it list all of the files associated with said project. Press return on your keyboard and simply rename it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this will result in large swaths of the project directory tree to be renamed, wreaking havoc on source control. The suggestion by @Mrunal is far more practical.

Answer (score 8):

Only change ***bundle display name*** in your ***-info.plist*** file.

It will update the title of the application written below the application icon. I guess this is what you required.

Answer (score 0):

sincerly I'll go with a grep on the terminal an change all the occurrences by hand.

`cd yourprojectdirectory`

`grep -r oldName .`

Comment: Quite an overkill - don't you think?