# Completely change a project's name in Xcode

Tags: xcode, file-management

I was making a game called "ladders", but now I'm calling it "bridges". All my file names and property and method names use "ladders", and I just want to completely change all the names to "bridges".

I just did a Find and Replace in the search navigator, and I got a zillion errors.

I think I'm just going rewrite the entire program, which will suck but I'll just be copy-pasting code from a few files, and rewriting the storyboard.

The main problem is the title of the application and the file names; I don't know how to properly change those. What's the correct procedure?

Comment: also  keep getting this lexical processor cannot find file thing whenever i just change the file names

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming projects in XCode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 3):

Edit the project name (shown describing the xcodeproj file) in the Project Navigator. After this is done, Xcode will ask you if you want it to update the rest of your project with the new name.

Comment: @ownageGuy: And thus, you learned to always use version control. It has to happen once to all of us.

Comment: Yeah, `git` is nicely integrated into Xcode. Check it out. It's pretty cool.