# Standard way to rename xcode project

Tags: xcode

After I create a project name for example Proj11, I'd like to change the name to Proj12.
So I use Project->Rename, then the name of the project to Proj12
But the project still contains several folders name Prlj11, and after I change the folders' name, the project can't been loaded.
So what is the standard way to rename my project as well as folder name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming projects in XCode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416677/renaming-projects-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Click on the project folder (blue folder with your app name on the top of the project navigator). Pull up the utilities (right pane), then file inspector. Your project name is there, change it to whatever you want. Then it will ask to save, keep all the files it selected for you selected, then press rename

Comment: this is the way to do it, but it has never fully worked for me. something always gets screwed up (xcode 5.0)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I found was on the apple developer site. Imagine that? You can follow the link below, but essentially it is:

1) click on the target in xcode, on the right in "Identify and Type" under name change the name and press the ENTER button on your keyboard.

2)a window will appear confirming the change and what it will change. Once you confirm it will make the changes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html

OR ANOTHER WAY AND EVEN EASIER:

left-click on the name project and rename. As soon as you rename it will ask you if you want to rename:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The folders you see in XCode navigators are not an actual folder/directories, these are virtual folders only to group your files.

And the folders you see in Finder, the path you manually set for the project, you need to rename them manually.